# questions on retrieving the name for a file being processed and writing processed lines to a new file

Tags: java

Currently, I have written a code segment which can read file from a folder, and read line by line for each file and replace some useless characters.

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
FileInputStream    fis;
BufferedReader br;
String   line;
for (File file : files) {
  fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println("Before: "+line);        
               String templine = line.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
           System.out.println("After: "+templine);
  };
```

Right now, I have two questions:

I need to write those processed lines into another backup file, which has the same name as the original file but will be placed in the another directory.

Thus, the first question is how can I get the name of the original file ?

The second question is how can I create a file with a given name and write these processed lines into this file.

Comment: `File` object has some very convenient methods :)

Answer (score 1):

`getName` is a method under the `File` class to get the name of the file.

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29):

> public String getName()
>
> Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this abstract
>   pathname. This is just the last name in the pathname's name sequence.
>   If the pathname's name sequence is empty, then the empty string is
>   returned.

To create a file with a name, use the [File constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) as mentioned here:

```
public File(String pathname)
```

> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
>   into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string,
>   then the result is the empty abstract pathname.